# Any way to change rsyslog configuration per user (for cron)?

Tags: cron, syslog, rsyslog

I am a user without sudo on a CentOS 7 system running rsyslog. I would like to log my cronjobs. Ideally, rsyslog would log all my user's cron activity to somewhere like `~/log/cron`.

There are good instructions in [several](https://askubuntu.com/a/121560/582404) [answers](https://askubuntu.com/a/966195/582404) about how to configure logging for cron in `/etc/rsyslog.conf` or equivalent, but I do not have access to that (nor to `/var/log/`).

Is there any per-user configuration for rsyslog? Or any cron(tab) setting for logging?

**Alternatives considered:**
I am already using crontab's `MAILTO=`. I specifically want a file on this system.
I know I could add `&>> ~/log/cron` to each crontab line—that's my backup plan. But I'd rather not have to, and I'd like to take advantage of syslog features like level and rotation.

Comment: Use systemd timers instead of cron jobs, and then you'll have access to all your logs via `journalctl --user`.

Comment: That sounds great, but I don't think it's available on CentOS 7:
https://superuser.com/a/1121451/163315
https://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=8767

Comment: Ah, bummer. It's been so long since I was running CentOS 7 regularly!

Comment: I realize it's only part of what you're after, but you can implement log rotation yourself using a tool like `logrotate` (which is included in centos 7).